# Viewing SSL/TLS keys on the browser

Tags: tls, web-browser, firefox

I would like to see the SSL/TLS keys of the websites which I'm communicating from the browser. Is there any simple way to view the SSL/TLS keys?

I read this [beautiful article](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html) in which the author gets to know about the keys by building the firefox in debug mode.

I would like to know if it exists in any browser, through which I can view the SSL/TLS keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your reference the SSL/TLS keys you refer to are the pre-master keys which can be used to decrypt a packet capture of the connection. Because of this use case they are only relevant for specific development and debugging. Therefore (and for security reasons) they are only available if you start the browser using a specific environment variable. And because the keys are binary and the tools you use to decrypt the traffic expect the keys in a file anyway it makes no sense to offer a GUI to show these keys.

Note that you don't need a debug mode of the browser to get these information. See [Decrypting TLS Browser Traffic With Wireshark – The Easy Way!](https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/).

Comment: thank you for reply, I followed the article and I can able to decrypt the traffic in wireshark. In the SSLkey log file I can able to see the values a follows:                                                                                                RSA 79153614e10c8dce 0303597252973a4b02cf462c69c484d735b0a35285195a383c97f2b529df32beb15a6fdcaf348fb147f2c10a4ee0f19a
I can understand that something following the 0303 is the random bytes generated by the client, but I didn't understand what the value immediately followed by RSA "79153614e10c8dce ",can you help on this?

Comment: @SaratG: this is a different question than your original. Please don't ask new questions inside comments but instead accept a reply which answered your original question as answer and ask a fully new question if needed. Apart from that see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/Key_Log_Format.

Comment: I don't have enough points(it seems 15 required) to upvote your answer, but yes your response is a fitting answer to my original question. Thank you very much.